# Perform calculation on multiple xml records

Tags: xml

How can I perform a simple calculation on each record of an xml?

For example, add 5% to each price rounded to the nearest dollar. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>

  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>

  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>

</bookstore>
```

Comment: Read the data in memory, do the calculation on the fields you need to update, write back the data to file. this can be done in multiple programming language, pick one.

Comment: What API you are using? Is it XQuery, XSLT, SQL, c#, etc.? Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the standard language for processing XML data is XSLT.
There are several versions of XSLT, starting with XSLT-1.0, which is widely implemented. So I chose a simple example in this version (which could be vastly improved in higher versions, if available):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>  
  
  <xsl:template match="price">
    <xsl:variable name="increase" select="1.05" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(round((.*100)*$increase) div 100,'#.00')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT-stylesheet performs the calculation on the value of all `price` elements and formats the output with [fn:format-number()](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_formatnumber.asp). The rest of the XML is just copied by the *identity template*. It gives the following output with your sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>

  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>31.50</price>
  </book>

  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>31.49</price>
  </book>

</bookstore>
```